# Scrollmagic triggers set by viewport

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, gsap, scrollmagic

I'm having an issue with scrollmagic. 
I'd like to be able to trigger all 3 animations in sequence on desktop, but on smaller viewports trigger them one by one as the user scrolls.

Having both of these sets of triggers active at the same time presents an unappealing experience where all elements animate twice

I have shown how this issue presents itself in the following codepen :

https://codepen.io/TomBismuth/pen/jYaybe

in short, I only want this to happen on desktop views

```
var sceneEntire = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
triggerElement: "#triggerall",
reverse: false
})
.setTween(entire) // trigger a TweenMax.to tween
.addIndicators({ name: "1 (duration: 0)" })
.addTo(mainController);
```

and this to only happen on mobile views

```
var scene1only = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
triggerElement: "#trigger1",
reverse: false
})
.setTween(row1) // trigger a TweenMax.to tween
.addIndicators({ name: "1 (duration: 0)" })
.addTo(mainController);

var scene2only = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
triggerElement: "#trigger2",
reverse: false
})
.setTween(row2) // trigger a TweenMax.to tween
.addIndicators({ name: "1 (duration: 0)" })
.addTo(mainController);

var scene3only = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
triggerElement: "#trigger3",
reverse: false
})
.setTween(row3) // trigger a TweenMax.to tween
.addIndicators({ name: "1 (duration: 0)" })
.addTo(mainController);
```

The end goal is to present the following animations (more complex version of the earlier example): https://codepen.io/TomBismuth/pen/ppWqwN in an appealing way for both desktop and mobile users on a website. Having them all trigger at once is unappealing on desktop, and having them trigger in sequence is unappealing on mobile.

Any help would be massively appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For the mobile version you need to set a triggerHook property for when the element is in the viewport. The values are between 0 and 1 where 0 represents the top of the viewport and 1 the very bottom.  You can only use increments of .1, so a value of .9 is 90% from the top (or 10% from the bottom) of the viewport depending on how you wish to phrase it.

So using the .9 value on your first scene, it would be:

```
if (window.innerWidth < 737) {

    var scene1only = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement: "#trigger1",
        triggerHook: .9,
        reverse: false
    })
    .setTween(row1) // trigger a TweenMax.to tween
    .addIndicators({ name: "1 (duration: 0)" })
    .addTo(mainController);

}
```